# How can you count the rows that occur only once in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I'd like to count the rows in a `DataFrame` that occur only once. For example, in the below example I'd return 2, since only row indexes 2 and 3 occur once:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 2, 3], 'b': [1, 1, 2, 2]})                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               

In [2]: df                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[2]: 
   a  b
0  1  1
1  1  1
2  2  2
3  3  2
```

(This is different from asking the number of unique rows, which in this case would be 3, per `df.drop_duplicates().shape[0]`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Invert boolean mask by `~` created by [`duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html) and `sum` for count `True`s values (`True` are processes like `1`):

```
out = (~df.duplicated(keep=False)).sum()
print (out)
2
```

**Details**:

```
print (df.duplicated(keep=False))
0     True
1     True
2    False
3    False

print (~df.duplicated(keep=False))
0    False
1    False
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

`(df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size() == 1).sum()`

Behind the scenes this is:

```
In [33]: df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size()                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[33]: 
a  b
1  1    2
2  2    1
3  2    1
dtype: int64
```

`size` counts the rows per combination, which you then sum for rows where it's 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a `numpy` option:

```
import numpy as np

_, cts = np.unique(df.values, axis=0, return_counts=True)
len(np.where(cts == 1)[0])
#2
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want the equivalent of `group by` and a `having` clause.

```
len(df.groupby(['a','b']).filter(lambda x: len(x) == 1).index)

2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the duplicated keep=False (negated) to count non duplicated.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 1, 2, 3], 'b': [1, 1, 2, 2]})
duplicates_s = df.duplicated(keep=False)
(~duplicates_s).sum()
```

Comment: Thanks ecortazar, but this approach has already been submitted: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54929830/1840471